# how to populate with other fields in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

My first collection value is :

**Collection 1:**

```
{
   _id:"5f82f1618cfa6d290c6271a9",
   name:"mehdi"
}
```

And second collection value is :

**Collection 2:**

```
{
    _id:"5f82f1618cfa6d290c6271aa",
    fid:"5f82f1618cfa6d290c6271a9",
    family:"parastar"
}
```

How can I populate base on ***_id*** in coll1 and ***fid*** in coll2?

I want to be, result like this:

```
{
   {
    _id:"5f82f1618cfa6d290c6271aa",
    fid:"5f82f1618cfa6d290c6271a9",
    family:"parastar"
   },
   name:"mehdi"
}
```

do you have any idea to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) in this way:

```
db.coll1.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "coll2",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "fid",
      as: "collection"
    }
  }
])
```

This query create a field called `collection` with the data you want:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5f82f1618cfa6d290c6271a9",
    "collection": [
      {
        "_id": "5f82f1618cfa6d290c6271aa",
        "family": "parastar",
        "fid": "5f82f1618cfa6d290c6271a9"
      }
    ],
    "name": "mehdi"
  }
]
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wzOpPd-o-3k)

Using `Mongoose` is the same, only write the query like this:

```js
var agg = await model.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "coll2",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "fid",
        as: "collection"
      }
    }
  ])
console.log(agg)
```

Comment: thanks, but I can't use aggregate because of my collections in separate databases :(

Comment: This is a very important detail because is not possible. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65754304/13464279) then. Also [Jira ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-34935) is open so it is not resolved.