# How to populate one to many relationship in mongoose with parent refrencing?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, foreign-keys, one-to-many, mongoose-populate

I have three collections: parent, child1, child2.

parent collection:

```
[{_id:1}, {_id:2}, {_id:3}]
```

child1 collection:

```
[{_id:1, child1:'a', parent:1}, {_id:2, child1:'b', parent:1}, {_id:3, child1:'c', parent:2}]
```

child2 collection:

```
[{_id:1, child1:'d', parent:2}, {_id:2, child1:'e', parent:3}]
```

> collections child1 and child2 referenced to parent collection.

now, I want a query in mongoose to get a result like this:

```
[
 {
  _id:1,
  child1:[{_id:1, child1:'a'}, {_id:2, child1:'b'}],
  child2:[],
 },
 {
  _id:2,
  child1:[{_id:2, child1:'c'}],
  child2:[{_id:1, child1:'d'}],
 },
 {
  _id:3,
  child1:[],
  child2:[{_id:2, child1:'e'}],
 },
]
```

my try in Aggregate is work correctly:

```
db.parent.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "child1",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "parent",
      "as": "child1"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "child2",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "parent",
      "as": "child2"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1XBBDa6myWU)

This works when the collections are in the same database but my collections in the separate database.

> e.g: parent collection in parent database and child1 and child2 collections in child database.

Do you have any idea for use aggregation across multiple databases or how can I use populate to solve this problem?

Comment: what have you tried so far? try aggregation with [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) you can use multiple lookups in single query.

Comment: my collections in seperate databeses e.g: parent collection in one database and child1 and child2 coll in another database.only I can use poplulate

Comment: Please update this details in your question as well not in comment, i don't think it is possible in single query look at this open [Jira ticket-34935](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-34935) and similar [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39222798/is-it-possible-to-do-a-lookup-aggregation-between-two-databases-in-mongodb), [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278814/mongodb-cross-database-query)

Answer (score 0):

As [mongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) says about `$lookup`:

> Performs a left outer join to an unsharded collection in the **same** database to filter in documents from the “joined” collection for processing.

So no, **it's not possible** do it accross DBs.

But, as an addition, using Mongo exists [db.getSiblingDB()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278814/mongodb-cross-database-query) option.

Docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getSiblingDB/) where says:

> Used to return another database without modifying the db variable in the shell environment.

So, this is not a `$lookup` but is an approach to have another Data Base data.